# Return true if value matches any value including nested object value

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have a nested object which consists of :

```
var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Stephen',
  age: 18,
  department: {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Operations'
  }
}
```

So if I have a string or an array of values that match any of the values including the nested object values in the collection, it will return true. I have tried using [`_.includes`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#includes) of lodash but I don't know how I can iterate through the nested object.

`_.includes(obj.department, 'Operations')`

What I am trying to do is more like

`_.includes(obj, ['Stephen', 'Operations'])` // return true

Comment: what are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if the value exists. `Array#some` returns immediately when the result of the predicate is `true`.

```js
var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Stephen',
  age: 18,
  department: {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Operations'
  }
}

function recursiveIncludes(obj) {
  var values = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
  
  return Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
    var current = obj[key];
 
    if(values.indexOf(current) !== -1) {
      return true;
    }
    
    if(typeof current === 'object' && current !== null) {
      return recursiveIncludes.apply(null, [current].concat(values));
    }
    
    return false;
  });
}

console.log('Operations: ', recursiveIncludes(obj, 'Operations'));
console.log('Moses, Stephen: ', recursiveIncludes(obj, 'Moses', 'Stephen'));
console.log('Moses, 58: ', recursiveIncludes(obj, 'Moses', 58));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive approach to it. It extracts all the properties of an object (the leaf properties) into an array. You can then call _.includes() on it.

```
var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Stephen',
  age: 18,
  department: {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Operations'
  }
}

function objToArray(obj) {
    var result = [];
    for (const prop in obj) {
        const value = obj[prop];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            result = result.concat(toArray(value)); 
        }
        else {
            result.push(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

_.includes(objToArray(obj), ['Stephen', 'Operations'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of strings, this will check and see if the property exists recursively.

```js
var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Stephen',
  age: 18,
  department: {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Operations'
  }
}

function hasValues(obj, props)
{
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    var item = obj[keys[i]];
    // If the item is a string or number, do a comparison
    if(typeof item === "string" || typeof item === "number"){
      var idx = props.indexOf(item);
      if(idx >= 0) props.splice(idx, 1);
    // If it's an object then search the object recursively
    } else if(typeof item === "object"){
      hasValues(item, props);
    }
  }

  return props.length === 0;
}

console.log(hasValues(obj, ['Stephen', 'Operations']))
console.log(hasValues(obj, [18, 1]))
console.log(hasValues(obj, [18, '13lkj4']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap) as a mechanism to flatten all the values taken from recursively using [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) inside the `flatMap` callback function. After obtaining all the values, we use [difference](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference) to get the difference between all the values between the `object` and the `values`. Lastly, we check the resulting difference if it is empty using [isEmpty](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEmpty).

```
function includesDeep(object, values) {
  return _(obj)
  .flatMap(function cb(v) { return _.isObject(v)? _.map(v, cb): v; })
  .thru(_.partial(_.difference, values))
  .isEmpty();
}

var result = includesDeep(obj, ['Stephen', 'Operations']);
```

```js
var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Stephen',
  age: 18,
  department: {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Operations'
  }
};

function includesDeep(object, values) {
  return _(obj)
  .flatMap(function cb(v) { return _.isObject(v)? _.map(v, cb): v; })
  .thru(_.partial(_.difference, values))
  .isEmpty();
}

var result = includesDeep(obj, ['Stephen', 'Operations']);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

the tests shows that you can't check multi-values & value in-depth with lodash includes,so you must write a function for yourself.

### Your solution

```
describe('includes', () => {
    var value = {
        foo: 'bar',
        fuzz: 'buzz',
        value2: {
            key: 'value'
        }
    };

    function includes(collection, values) {
        return [].concat(values).every((value) => {
            return Object.keys(collection).some((key) => {
                let it = collection[key];
                return typeof it == 'object' ? includes(it, value) : _.includes(it, value);
            })
        });
    }

    it('check single value', () => {
        expect(includes(value, 'bar')).toBe(true);
        expect(includes(value, 'baz')).toBe(false);
    });

    it('check multi values', () => {
        expect(includes(value, ['bar', 'buzz'])).toBe(true);
        expect(includes(value, ['baz', 'buzz'])).toBe(false);
    });

    it('check value in depth', () => {
        expect(includes(value, 'value')).toBe(true);
        expect(includes(value, 'no-exists')).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

### Test

```
describe('includes', () => {
    var value = {
        foo: 'bar',
        fuzz: 'buzz',
        value2: {
            key: 'value'
        }
    };

    it('check single value', () => {
        expect(_.includes(value, 'bar')).toBe(true);
        expect(_.includes(value, 'baz')).toBe(false);
    });

    it('check multi values', () => {
        expect(_.includes(value, ['bar', 'buzz'])).toBe(false);
        expect(_.includes(value, ['baz', 'buzz'])).toBe(false);
    });

    it('check value in depth', () => {
        expect(_.includes(value, 'value')).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

```js
function includes(collection, values) {
    return [].concat(values).every(function (value) {
        return Object.keys(collection).some(function (key) {
            var it = collection[key];
            return (typeof it == 'object') ? includes(it, value) : _.includes(it, value);
        });
    });
}


var obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Stephen',
  age: 18,
  department: {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Operations'
  }
};


var tests=[
  "Operations",
  "Non-Existing Value",
  ['Stephen', 'Operations'],
  ['Stephen', 'Non-Existing Value'],
];


tests.forEach(function(test){
  console.log("includes(obj,"+JSON.stringify(test)+") => "+ includes(obj,test));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know. Which is why I asked are there any utility functions that would allow us to use something like _.includes() but having the ability to iterate through the value in depth as well.

Comment: write a function for your solution based on the-third library,that it's easy.why depend other libraries? search libraries may be cost your lot of the time.

Comment: I have updated my answer,to see the `Your solution`,the code support something you thought.